# How to compare two files, line by line, but only on selected values

Tags: shell, awk, while-loop

I want to compare two files, line by line, and check if the left/top coords in the first file are the same in the second.

I've an issue concerning this command in UNIX Shell:

```
awk -F"px" '{print $1}'
```

To sum up I would like to compare the px in two Html documents:

**Input:**

The first:

```
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:76px; top:26px;">
```

The second:

```
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:61px; top:28px;">
```

**Process:**

```
i=1
left=1
top=2
while [ "$linesBodyPdf1" > "$i" ]
do
echo "------Line $i--------"
px1=`echo "left V1=" && echo $bodyPdf1 | awk -F"px" '{print $left}' | awk -F"left:" '{print $2}'`
echo $px1
px2=`echo "top V1=" && echo $bodyPdf1 | awk -F"px" '{print $top}' | cut -c7-9`
echo $px2

px1=`echo "left V2=" && echo $bodyPdf2 | awk -F"px" '{print $left}' | awk -F"left:" '{print $2}'`
echo $px1
px2=`echo "top V2=" && echo $bodyPdf2 | awk -F"px" '{print $top}' | cut -c7-9`
echo $px2

left=$(($left + 2))
top=$(($top + 2))
i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

**Output:**

```
------Line 1--------
left V1= 0px; top:0px;" width="595" height="841" src="page1.png"> <div class="txt" style="position:absolute;
top V1= <i
left V2= 0px; top:0px;" width="595" height="841" src="page1.png"> <div class="txt" style="position:absolute;
top V2= <i
```

Instead of it:

```
------Line 1--------
left V1= 76
top V1= 26
left V2= 61
top V2= 28
```

I don't know how to do...
Please help me!

Comment: Still not clear what you really want. Forget about the  process you've mentioned here. Can you explain in words what do you want while comparing two files ?

Comment: I would like to compare pixels div positions (left & top). I have a first html document with a left & top position and a second with a left and top position. I want to get the number of each px and make a difference to see if the first html document is the same of the second.

Comment: So, you want to compare two files, line by line, but pairing only lines that contain actual left/top coords?

Comment: Yes I want to compare two files, line by line, and check if the left/top coords in the first file are the same in the second.

Comment: I've added this to your question and title, but please read [how to ask questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help you, but you should put in some minimal effort when asking the question, so it's clear, unambiguous, and general enough for others that may come by.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two files with `left`/`top` coordinates, one pair per line, always `left` value before `top` value, with possible "noise" lines in between, then the simplest solution would be to first filter the values out (for example with `sed`) and then compare line by line (for example with `awk`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: compare.sh FILE1 FILE2

filter() {
    sed -nE 's/.*left\s*:\s*([0-9]+)\s*px.*top\s*:\s*([0-9]+)\s*px.*/\1 \2/gp'
}

awk 'NR==FNR { x[NR]=$0 }
     NR>FNR  { print "Line " FNR ": " x[FNR] (x[FNR]==$0 ? " == ":" != ") $0 }'
     <(filter <"$1") <(filter <"$2")
```

With the `first.html` and `second.html` input, the output looks like:

```
$ cat first.html 
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:76px; top:26px;">
<span>
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:74px; top:25px;">

$ cat second.html 
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:61px; top:28px;">
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:74 px; top: 25px;">
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:61px; top:28px;">

$ ./compare.sh first.html second.html
Line 1: 76 26 != 61 28
Line 2: 74 25 == 74 25
Line 3:  != 61 28
```

Comment: I can't do that cause I've two differents counters "left" and "top" which takes +2 at each end of loop. I would like increment like this $($left) or $($top). You understand?

Comment: I can't say I do. Can you please post a sample input in your question?

Comment: Great, but I meant sample text input from the file you are processing. And please add some expected output also.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, completely rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I have solved my issue.

I writed like this:

```
'{print $left}'
```

Instead of it:

```
'{print $'"${left}"'}'
```

After I can increment my var by doing:

```
left=$(($left + 2))
```

And this write

```
'{print $2}'
'{print $4}'
'{print $6}'
'{print $8}'
'{print $10}'
...
```

That was what I wanted

Thanks to all for your help all the same.

Cheers!!!!!